# Network not working on openstack instance

Tags: openstack

I've openstack-install (single setup) juno,
after creating one vm on the ext-net network, I can't SSH to it, nor ping it.

```
~$ nova list
+--------------------------------------+--------+--------+------------+-----    --------+-------------------+
| ID                                   | Name   | Status | Task State |  Power State | Networks          |
+--------------------------------------+--------+--------+------------+-------------+-------------------+
| 9d5127db-ff3a-466a-afc5-524be4ea7ee5 | test02 | ACTIVE | -          | Running     | ext-net=10.0.5.13 |
+--------------------------------------+--------+--------+------------+-------------+-------------------+

~$ ping 10.0.5.13
PING 10.0.5.13 (10.0.5.13) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.100.1.139 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.100.1.139 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.100.1.139 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 10.0.5.13 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 3016ms

~$ nova ssh test02
ERROR: No public addresses found for 'test02'.
```

any ideas what to check ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to associate your ubuntu-net with your instances and associate a floating IP.